# Sencha Architect 3 - Where is the soap proxy in the toolbox?

Tags: extjs, soap, sencha-architect

I am using Sencha Architect 3 build (3.0.4.1386) with framework enterprise 4.2.2.1144, question is that I do not see the soap proxy in the toolbox, is there a way to add this to the toolbox?

I noticed on the Sencha sites that there is no conclusive answer so far on this question.

The folder \4.2.2.1144\src\data\soap is present with a \Proxy.js and \Reader.js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the soap proxy is only included in the Sencha Complete version of ExtJS which you may not have a licence for.